# Why Facebook "like page" response is wrong?

Tags: iphone, ios, json, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have implemented the functionality of facebook "Page Like" in my iPhone application. I am using https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes/18168151511?access_token=xxxxxxxxx link to like FB page. this page returns a json in response. If page is liked then its response json is like this

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "category": "Local business",
         "name": "Sky Zone",
         "id": "xxxxxxxx",
         "created_time": "2013-02-04T07:51:15+0000"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/100001965134734/likes?target_id=18168151511&access_token=AAAFJTR2OINoBAKz6HZAYcZCEcLOZCegJnLk0vqPSqxsBOQZC8kb0I6xEYy2GXqsOROicqMMwpMEhZCw8tpZBP2AiAiyQf69vv4EWalZCHRmjwZDZD&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=18168151511"
   }
}
```

if page is not liked then it returns an empty json. But for some ids it returns empty json while they have liked this page but still it returns empty json.
Any help plzzzz I am really stuck on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a facebook side issue and this problem is not resolved yet. for some of IDs it works good but for some of IDs it returns empty in either case. If we go through proper channel then this link is very helpful http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/facebook-api-check-if-a-user-is-fan-of-a-facebook-page/20/
In my case i am applying this on iOS so this link was not too much helpful for me. Finally I just checked the statement in my UIWebView. If user liked this page then there are only 2 cases of statement,

> 1. You and 10,000 other people liked this page.
> 2. You, yourFriendName, YourfriendName and 10,000 other people liked this page.

So If you fined word "You and" or "You, " then it means user liked this page otherwise user has not liked this page.